# How to recover the folder /var/lib/* in centos 6 when I accidentally deleted it?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

Unfortunately, I deleted the folder `/var/lib/*` in centos 6. How to recover this folder?

Answer (score 1):

if you did `rm` to delete the content of this folder, there is no way to undo it. Packages which have put their data there will recreate their directory structures if you reinstall the rpm, like for example MySQL would do that, but the data is still lost. I hope you have a backup?

Comment: current to cannot perform command yum install , how to help me carry out the command yum install  that?

you look

rpm -q centos-release yum rpm python

package centos-release is not installed

package yum is not installed

package rpm is not installed

package python is not installed